# OpenMediaVault Share not accessible when OMV account name equals Windows username

Tags: windows-7, samba, username

I have a couple of SMB shares set up with OpenMediaVault:

- Public, runs fine
- Private, with username "Private" runs also fine
- Dani with omv username "Dani" and Windows username "Dani" can be
  accessed via Android App (Solid Explorer) but not with Windows, I
  also specified the "login with different username" and applied Domains 
  like "NEMESIS\Dani" for the username (NEMESIS is the OMV hostname). Also when  I add a user named "Hans" it can be access with Windows.

Is this behavior normal and can it be avoided somehow?

Comment: Is the password of the windows account the same as the password on the smb client or not?